# django url issue using mutiple regular expressions

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am having an issue with an url and regular expression I get the error

```
AttributeError: Generic detail view EmployeeDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

What I am to achieve is to get to a user detail page coming from a specific project

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeDetails'),
```

my view is :

```
Project detail :
class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).team_id.members.all()
            context['team_name'] = team_name
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return context

class EmployeeDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee_name = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['employee_name'] = employee_name
        return context
```

HTML link :

```
<span class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"><a href="{% url 'website:EmployeDetails' pk1 = project.id pk2 = member.id %}"> Show Results</a>
```

models:
MyUser models:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_hr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
```

Team models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")
```

could you please help me to figure it ? thx you ;)

Comment: Usually, your URL pattern for a `DetailView` would contain a single group `(?P<pk>[0-9]+)`. Django would use the pk from the URL to fetch the object with that ID. In your case you have `(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)` and `(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)`, so Django doesn't know what to do. If the URL was `/project/5/7/`, what object do you want to see the detail for?

Comment: it would be project.id = 5 and member.id = 7; a member can be part of multiple project so I would like to see the detail of the member for this exact project

Comment: you have to set pk_url_kwarg to pk1 if pk1 is the MyUser object or pk2 if pk2 is MyUser object. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal Where do I have to set pk_url_kwarg exactly ?

Comment: Using `related_name='members'` is confusing. You are following the relationship backwards from `MyUser` to `Team`, so `related_name='teams'` would make more sense. Also you don't need `_id` in foreign key names - `team` would be better than `team_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't know how to use `pk1` and `pk2` to fetch the object for the view. I would override the `get_object` method and fetch the object there.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# Note mixin should come first
class EmployeeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    ...
```

Another option is to set `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk2'`. This tells Django that `pk2` is the primary key of the `MyUser` object, so there is no need to override `get_object`. However if you do this, then Django will ignore the `pk1` from the URL.

```
class EmployeeDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk2'
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'
```

Comment: great I used pk_url_kwarg = 'pk2' and it worked .. would you recommend your option to be better  ?

Comment: As I said, if you use `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk2'`, then Django will ignore `pk1. The URLs `/project/5/7/` and `/project/500/7/` will both show the object with `pk=7`, regardless of whether the project id is correct.

Comment: Oh ok ok so definitively option 1 is better could you explain employee=self.kwargs['pk1'] what is refered to employee ?

Comment: I should have written `project=self.kwargs['pk1']`. I'm assuming that your `MyUser` model has a foreign key `project` to the `Project` model. You haven't shown your models in the question so you may have to adjust that part of the code.

Comment: using project = self.kwargs I get :No MyUser matches the given query.
I will add you my models ..

Comment: I guess that what is available to me is company, email, first_name, id, is_active, is_admin, is_candidate, is_employee, is_hr, last_login, last_name, logentry, members, password, project, response, team when actualy I would need members.id

Comment: You could try `members__project=self.kwargs['pk1']`. Or, if you changed the related name to `teams`, then `teams__project=self.kwargs['pk1']`.

Comment: it worked, thx you very much ;) could you explain the members__project first time I see it

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Alasdair Last question if I may ;) how do I create a link ? this one is not working <span class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"><a href="{% url 'website:EmployeDetails' pk1 = project.id pk2 = member.id %}"> Show Results</a>

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in the comments. Start a new question instead.

Comment: Sorry ;) I created ;)